# How to make sure my wordpress theme does not get broken when an update occurs on a parent theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a child theme which uses **sydney**(parent) and created a separate folder for it. 
In order for me to customize the parent I need to re-write the css rules within style.css inside child theme, but I was wondering what if later parent theme get an update and looses all the classes and id which I am refering from my child style.css

```
/*
    Theme Name: x
    Theme URL: www.x.com
    Description: X Theme
    Author: X
    Author URI: www.xyz.com
    Version: 1.0
    Template: sydney
*/

.wp-custom-header .wp-custom-header-video-button {
    bottom: 50%;
}

.wp-custom-header .wp-custom-header-video-button {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.wp-custom-header .wp-custom-header-video-button:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.fa-pause {
    color: #065fe4;
}

.fa-play{
    color: #065fe4;
}

#mainnav ul li a {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 20px 0px 0px;
}
```

All above css classes and I am referring to the parent theme, bc all the header.php, content.php, page.php and others file exists there, Does that mean I should have my own version of all these pages? if So what's the use of creating a child theme, when I can create my own Parent theme, kinda confusing!
What is the best way so that no matter the parent theme gets updated I would not want the child theme to get affected at any time!

Comment: it's a good idea to worry about not breaking the theme but it's not your work. it's the work of the developper of the theme. when the developper update his theme he must think about backward compatibility and when it's not possible, he must prevent users of theme long time in advance in order that end users have time to correct the child theme in order to not break the site display.

Comment: @mmm I like ur answer, this makes more sense! thanks! maybe u can add as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 0):

You should create a "Child Theme" for your desired theme.
This way you can change the stuff you want to overwrite and it won't get lost during updates from your parent theme.

This should help you https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Edit: Sorry i missread your Post at first.

The advantage for Child Themes are:

- You don't need to copy the whole theme again. Just take the files you
  need to change into the child theme  and you are done. The rest will
  be used from your parent theme.
- You still get the updates for your parent theme (and thus also for your child theme). Creating your own "copied" parent theme may stop updates, or even worse, updates still are functional but will overwrite your customizations.

So unless you won't create a complete new theme, you really should create a child theme. This way you also see exactly which files you have changed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple and short - you can't. You have to test your child the once there is a new main theme realease.

Answer (score -1):

Just do:

1. put your CSS to a separate file.
2. connect in your css file after the css of that theme.

i.e.:

```
<link href="parent-theme-css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="your-theme-css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

No matter how `parent-theme-css.css` changes, your `your-theme-css.css` will rewrite it where needed.

Comment: do you think, that this type of calling( `<link href="parent-theme-css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` ) `js/css` files are right choice for wordpress?

Comment: put ABCDE and DEFG instead. This answer is not about how to link your css in wp, if that is the question you have, ask it. While OP question is how to solve theme's css attachment sequence. And yes - if you work with core files not from WP backend but directly - you can use exact what I referred to, cuz this is how its written in the headers of any html page.

Comment: even if it's not direct answer to question, it don't mean, that somebody need to provide one of the worst decision `how to make something`.You just may answer to the question without providing bad options of how to do it

Comment: Could you please be specific and advise me on why the option I provided is the "one of the worst decision" - just for my understanding. Thanks

Comment: because any `cms/frameworks` have their own way to call `css/js` files. and here is ex. `how to add css/js into wordpress`: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/ . with your code you made dinamic added css file into static, which may be changed only from the `file`, where you wrote your code

Comment: you call it a dynamic added css, huh? niiiiice. Its always nice that you highlight words like `css` or `file` as a `code`. Thats `about` all i `could` answer, `all best` -)

Comment: I can suggest you to take away from `wordpress`, untill you'll learn a little more about it. Because of "developers" like you other developers got a lot of problem like a fixing a lot of bugs from client's website, and only after it do our own changes

Comment: and also, as you wrotten `put ABCDE and DEFG instead`, if the word I used not fully described what there doing something, it's don't metter for that , your choice of code was bad for sharing it as answer